# how to prevent the touch screen in windows-CE?

Tags: windows-ce

how to prevent the touch screen in windows-CE ?

by C# code

thanks

Comment: Do you want to *block* the touch screen, i.e. make it impossible for users to use the screen? Is it in your application or system-wide? Be more descriptive in your question.

Comment: this what i need -  block the touch screen !!!, can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The comment by Eugene is appropriate.  Knowing if you need to shut off all touch input just for your app or the whole OS, and if you need to do it forever or if you may want to turn this behavior on/off are very relevant.

There's nothing in the OS that generically allows you to shut down the touchscreen.  You might be able to install a hook and not pass on events, but we don't really know what you need to do.  It's probably even possible to adjust the driver registry entries to have the touchpanle driver not load.  Again, it would depend on your exact requirements if that would be useful.